# Custom TextBox in a ToolStripTextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a ToolStripTextBox but I want to set it my own MyCustomTextBox. It is a class that I use in other places that make some validation.

First I tried to set Control ot TextBox properties, but they are read only and not Overridable.

Then I tried to set my control in the constructor of a derived class:

```
Public Class MyCustomSingleToolStripButton
  Inherits ToolStripTextBox

  Sub New()
    MyBase.New(New MyCustomTextBox)
  End Sub
End Class
```

As it is suggested in by the documentation of ToolStripTextBox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58xwdff2.aspx

```
Public Sub New(c As Control)
```

It compiles ok but I get an exception in run time, microsoft suggest me that calling the empty constructor I´m going to get a nice TextBox, but not mine. To my surprise I see that there is no constructor receiving a Control, it is not in Object Brower nor it appears in the intellisense box.

Last I tried to derive my class directly from ToolStripControlHost, but it looks really bad and I have to customize all

Is there a standard and reasonable way to do this?

Comment: Is this Winforms/WPF/Silverlight/ASP/Etc?

Comment: You really do need to derive from ToolStripControlHost to embed your own custom control.  "It looks really bad" just doesn't help us help you.

Comment: What I mean is that the TextBox that appears with my ToolStripControlHost derived class has not width, it adapts to the entered text, the borders are rounded, the height is less than the standard TextBox, the background is white in some places, but in the back of the text is gray. I replaced my previous derived ToolStripTextBox (it looked right) with this with the same settings but it seems not take them into account. I should configure all the visual settings in my class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On thing you can do is create a new version of your textbox that inherits from ToolStripTextBox and add it as a new object to the Items collection of the toolstrip:

```
Public Class MyTextbox
    Inherits ToolStripTextBox
    Public Sub New()
        Me.Text = "Test"
    End Sub
End Class

ToolStrip1.Items.Add(New MyTextbox)
```

If you add the control to your project as a User Control, it will automatically be added to the drop down list for toolstrip in the designer.